# 65% CPU & 15% Memory with Tensorflow on Google Cloud ML

Tags: tensorflow

I'm running a Google Cloud ML Job using  `"scaleTier": "BASIC_GPU"`, and the following chart outlines details on the utilisation:

[image: Job Details in Google Cloud ML Engine]

I'm executing an Experiment using `learn_runner.run(...)` on a Custom Estimator and feed the input using a pipeline based approach using file name queue to read data.

Is using the pipeline based approach the main reason for the low Memory utilisation and is there something I should consider to optimize training utilisation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All sorted with the new Dataset API.